# Problem with homebrew recipe for ctags

Tags: homebrew

I was trying to install `ctags` using `homebrew`:

```
>brew install ctags
==> Downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/ctags/ctags-5.8.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/ctags-5.8.tar.gz
==> Downloading patches

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
Error: Failure while executing: /usr/bin/curl -f#LA Homebrew\ 0.9.4\ (Ruby\ 1.8.7-358;\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 10.8.5) https://raw.github.com/gist/4010022/8d0697dc87a40e65011e2192439609c17578c5be/ctags.patch -o 000-homebrew.diff
```

Any idea how I can troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HTTP 404 Error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404): Not found. This means the URL referenced something that no longer exists at that location. The problem isn't with `curl`, the problem is with the homebrew recipe for `ctags` -- it's out of date.

You can see this for yourself by pointing a browser to the patch URL that the homebrew recipe is trying to the URL that `curl` is trying to download from: https://raw.github.com/gist/4010022/8d0697dc87a40e65011e2192439609c17578c5be/ctags.patch

You get a 404 Not Found error from GitHub.

Try updating your recipes, it's likely the `ctags` recipe is out of date:

```
brew update
```

If that doesn't resolve the problem, report it as an issue for the `ctags` recipe here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues

Comment: `brew update` fixed it.